# Accepting parameters on process startup from cli

Tags: java, process, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Seems to me that the best approach for accepting process parameters on process startup is to provide key-value pair elements.
E.g. `port=8089` etc.
But most program seem to accept the arguments in a predefined order i.e. just `8089`.
I was wondering am I wrong? Are there are other issues with key-value pairs I am overlooking?

I am refering to the classic `String[] args` in `main`

Comment: Key value pairs need to be parsed, which programmers are too lazy for, and the JRE doesn't come with a widely-used getopt-style library.

Comment: There are [a number of common conventions for passing command-line arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Arguments). There isn't necessarily a correct one. I tend to use Apache's [Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) to parse/enforce my chosen format.

Comment: @themel:Why parsed?A simple `split("=")` would work fine

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this :

1. **Passing in key value pairs** :

   `java MainClass -Dkey1=value1 -Dkey2=value2`

   Using `System.getProperty("key1")` you can access the value.
2. **Arguments to the Main Class**

   `java MainClass value1 value2`

   You can access value1, value2 from the args array in your main method
   `public static void main (String[] args)`

Comment: `-Dkey1=value1` doesn't this risk the chance to be confused with java parameters?

Comment: It won't as long as key1 is self explanatory. e.g : `jim.age`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's easier to just grab an argument by index instead of keying, so nothing wrong with key-value pairs, just that predefined order is the lazy way.

Along similar Properties line, found an example of parsing your input args into a Property object: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/CreatePropertiesfromStringarray.htm